# Can SSRS create new columns instead of adding another row?

Tags: dynamic, ssrs-2008, grouping, ssrs-tablix

My report shows event level information but when the event has multiple records assigned, it creates additional rows in the report when I'd like for it to add additional columns instead.

[image: One Column, Multiple Rows]

From my screenshot, you can see Drive ID 675276 (Autoo Owners Insurance) and Drive ID 681980 (Liberty Co. HS) have two (or three) rows for the event if they have more than one incentive assigned.

Is there a way I have have SSRS create additional columns for Incentives instead of displaying the records on individual rows?

My ideal solution would be similar to the image below:

[image: Additional Columns]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes but in a kind of different way than you're currently envisioning.

Basically, recreate your table as a matrix, set the row grouping to be the Drive ID field. Matrix' have a Column Group in addition to a row group - set this Group (and the header for that column) to be your Incentive field, and then finally set the value for that column to be:

```
=Iif(IsNothing(Fields!<<incentive field>>.Value), Nothing, "Y")
```

What that will get you is a table with a column for each different Incentive type, and a "Y" in the appropriate columns to show that this event has those Incentives

Comment: Interesting, sounds like it's the way I need to go. Would I make the DriveID a parent group? Never used a matrix before.